# No echos in bash script in Jenkins

Tags: ruby, bash, jenkins, rvm

I'm writing a Pipeline script for Jenkins on Mac that needs to execute a couple of sh steps. Some of them involve RVM and Bundler ...

```
sh '#!/bin/bash -xl' +
    ' && rvm list' +
    ' && rvm use 2.3.1' +
    ' && gem install bundler' +
    ' && which bundler'
```

As you can see I have to use the hashbang to make RVM and Bundler to work, i.e having to be in a Login Shell but the problem is I don't see any log output for this in Jenkins anymore, even with -xl flag.

Does somebody know why log output is omitted and how to enable it for this?

**UPDATE**:

```
sh returnStdout: true, script: '#!/bin/bash -xl && rvm list && rvm use 2.3.1 && gem install bundler && which bundler'
```

Log Output:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[app_ios_test_automation] Running shell script
[Pipeline] echo
```

Answer (score 0):

The "sh" function has optional parameters.  If you call it like you're doing, you won't get the standard output of the script.

If you go into your pipeline job definition, where you specify the pipeline script itself, you should see a link labeled "Pipeline Syntax". This allows you to experiment with the pipeline steps that are enabled in your Jenkins instance.  If you select "sh" from the dropdown and then click the "Advanced" button, you'll see the additional options you can set, including the "returnStdout" flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the syntax for sh command @David & @Jacob! However it still wont work for me. Please see my update above on how I call the sh and how the log output for that part looks.

Comment: In addition, other, more simple sh calls in my pipeline script that don't use the hashbang do log output just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on David Karr's answer, you're probably looking for something like this:

`sh(returnStdout: true, script: "your script here")`